# Microsoft.Graph update from 4.x.x to 5.x.x

Tags: c#, .net, email, .net-core

I updated Microsoft.Graph package from 4.31 to 5.19 (latest version available) but I'm having errors at my Email manager.

[image: List of errors I'm having]

Comment: Upgrading from v4 to v5 is a big change with a lot of changes. Take a look at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md

Comment: The two biggest underestimated changes are that the DTOs are now stateful objects regarding serialization due to the backing store and that you can't serialize/deserialize graph objects anymore yourself by simply using System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.